# GLib-GObject Warning and Errors when I merge two working app made using QTCreator on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, raspberry-pi, glib

I have two application that was created using *QTCreator (Qt Creator 4.2.0
Based on Qt 5.7.1)* ony my *Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ (Raspbian 9.6 stretch)*.

The first application is a Non-qt Plain C++ Application that uses opencv. Where the application would do face detection. The second application is a QT Widgets Application where I have just some QDialogs.

Both applications build and run on the pi. They run perfectly and do what they're supposed to do. Though the QT Widget Application gives this warning during runtime:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
```

But it still works very fine.

**The problem comes when I merge this two application**. Even when I'd just put these lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
LIBS += `pkg-config --libs opencv4`
```

on the .pro file of my QT Widget Application so that I can use opencv on that application it gives me these warnings and errors:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin

(rpi2:1613): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'

(rpi2:1613): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(rpi2:1613): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'

(rpi2:1613): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(rpi2:1613): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(rpi2:1613): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(rpi2:1613): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
```

I tried researching about it and what I found out that the possible reason for this could be when QT was upgraded to 5.7.0-1, the widget style GTK is not available for QT5 apps (I saw it [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214147&p=2)). And the workaround for this would be to put this `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk2` or this `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` on my /etc/environment then reboot. But both of them didn't work.

**What do I need to do to solve this problem?**

Comment: What do you mean by ‘merge this two application’? Can you explain it in terms of what the compiler and linker do?

It looks like you might have two copies of the GTK+ code being run when your application is started up. GTK+ registers its types (such as `GtkWidget`) dynamically; if the init code is run twice, the second run will produce these errors. This could happen if one (or both) of your applications statically linked in GTK+; or if one of your applications links to GTK+ 2 and one links to GTK+ 3.

Comment: Basically what I mean is I want to put my face detection app in my qt widget app. Like I want to have a push button that when I click it the camera would open and the app would do face detection. That's basically my goal. But when I try to put some of the face detection code on the qt widget app it gives off those errors above during run time.

Comment: I don’t think anyone can help without an explanation of what you’re doing with the linker, since that’s the relevant part of the compilation process to these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same kind of errors, after changing several settings with `qt5ct`. Some applications (like `VirtualBox`, for example, and even `qt5ct`), didn't run anymore.

The solution was to clean the qt5ct configuration:

```sh
~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf
```